# My PCL that uses async await compiles fine, but VS2012 intellisense shows red squigglies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asynchronous

I just noticed that VS12 is showing compilation errors in the editor (red squigglies) for code that it is compiling just fine.

For example, I have:

```
string s = await webclient.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

This code compiles cleanly. My PCL is created and a project that uses it works as expected.

However, in the VS editor this line has a red squiggly under it and the popup reads

```
Cannot convert expression type 'void' to async method return type 'string'
```

Which would make sense if `Bcl.Async` wasn't installed from Nuget, but is.

What do I have to do to get VS to use the same compiler/libraries/whatever for the editor that it is using to actually compile my project?

FWIW, I created a brand new PCL project (.NET 4.5, SL 4+, WP8, .NET for Store apps) and added my source files to it. Then I added Bcl.Async and net.http via NuGet.  Same problem.

Comment: Can you post the source code of the method that contains the await call of webclient?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the intellisense database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen this behavior in VS2012, but I have seen it in ReSharper.

You can disable the ReSharper squigglies in the options; I just ignore them.

Comment: I can turn off Code Inspection and that makes them go away (yay!) but I don't want ALL code inspection turned off. Do you know how to turn off just red squigglies?

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact cause of them, but you could follow-up with Re# support.